# Example of dependent but conditional independent

Tags: probability, statistics

There are a lot of events that are independent and conditional independent.

Is there any events that are dependent but conditionally independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $X_1,\ldots, X_5$ be independent and $P(X_i=0)=P(X_i=1)=\frac12$. Now let

- $X=X_1$
- $Y=(\max\{X_2,X_3\}=X_1)$
- $Z=(\max\{X_4,X_5\}=X_1)$

If $X_1=0$, the latter two simplify to $X_2=X_3=0$ and $X_4=X_5=0$, which are clearly independant.
If $X_1=1$, they simplify to $X_2=1\lor X_3=1$ and $X_4=1\lor X_5=1$, which are clearly independant.
However, $Y,Z$ without conditioning on $X_1$ are dependant.

Comment: Just wondering why Y and Z without condition are dependent? Thanks.

Comment: $P(Y)=P(Z)=\frac12$, but $P(Y,Z)=\frac12\cdot \frac34\cdot\frac34+\frac12\cdot\frac14\cdot\frac14=\frac5{16}\ne\frac14$.

Comment: That is an excellent example. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @HagenvonEitzen, can you explain this a bit please?