# A real world example of events which are conditionally independent but unconditionally dependent.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I would like to know some practical example of the same. I found this answer here: [Example of dependent but conditional independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758272/example-of-dependent-but-conditional-independent)

Definitely a great one answer but I was looking for some real-world example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a school as example:
the school is taking an exam in which students either pass or fail and they may be able to cheat too. so the score of students are dependent to each other(however the situation is hard to be analyzed). now imagine that school performs actions to avoid cheating in a way which no one will be able to cheat so that every student will answer the exam only based on his/her knowledge and the score will not be dependent on any other student. so under normal conditions(students can cheat)the probability of someone pass is dependent and under the anti-cheating conditions the passing probability is independent.